# How to Display Data from Array Using forloop in Jinja Template?

Tags: python, flask

I want to display data in the table using flask forloop.
I have the Following Array called "mainarray"

```py
[
    ('x', 'y', 'z'),
    ('a', 'b', 'c'),
    ('m', 'n', 'o')
]
```

Currently, I am using following method

```html
{% for newmainarray in mainarray %}
    <td>{{ newmainarray [0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ newmainarray [1] }}</td>
    <td>{{ newmainarray [2] }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Currently, it's working for me, but I have seen in some tutorials that we can display data by using  **{{newmainarray.keyname}}**.

However, it's not working for me. I will be very thankful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Try `{{ newmainarray.0 }}` etc. instead

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `{{newmainarray.keyname}}` since `mainarray` contains arrays/tuples and not dictionaries. in order to use `.keyname` pattern you need to set `mainarray` as following:

```
[
     {'key':'x', 'other_key':'y'},
]
```

Alternatively, you can access `newmainarray` with the array index as `newmainarray.index_number`